# Simulation log file is not generated for the karate-gatling feature execution using gatling highchart bundle script file

Tags: karate

I have downloaded the gatling-highchart-bundle zip..

placed the karate feature file and karate-galtling simulation file in the user-files/simulation folder under the highchart-bundle.

set the classpath of the karate feature file folder in the gatling.sh & gatling.bat file.

When I trigger the execution, reports are not generated ?

Can anyone help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Please assume that what you are asking for is not supported. Read the karate-gatling documentation to see what is supported: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling

Comment: Thanks for your response... I have found the solution.. Now i am able to generate the log file & gatling report via gatling highchart bundle